# How do I derive the BUILD file from a produced target?

Tags: bazel

Our monolith repo looks something like this:

```
├── bin
    └── ...
└── source
    ├── foo
        ├── BUILD
        └── ...
    └── bar
        ├── BUILD
        └── ...
    └── ...
```

We have thousands of BUILD files producing thousands of targets into the bin directory.

Now that we have all these compiled binaries in the bin directory, it would be nice to have a method for deriving which BUILD file put it there.

I don't want to hand-write a tool that recursively parses all of the BUILD file's build rules and prints the answer.  Is this something that can be achieved with bazel query?

Most of our build rules are pretty typical:

```
cc_binary(
    name="foo",
    ...
)
py_binary(
    name="bar.py",
    ...
)
```

The end goal would be to run something like:

```
where-source ./bin/foo
./source/foo/BUILD created ./bin/foo
```

Answer (score 2):

If you trim off the `bin/` (I assume you're using `--symlink_prefix`?), you can use `bazel query`:

```
# Where did bin/foo/bar/baz get defined?
$ bazel query foo/bar/baz
//foo/bar:baz
```

Or, to get detailed info about the location:

```
$ bazel query --output=location foo/bar/baz
 /home/kchodorow/gitroot/proj/source/foo/bar/BUILD:3:1: go_binary rule //foo/bar:baz
```

Or, to get the definition of the target itself:

```
$ bazel query --output=build foo/bar/baz
go_binary(
    name = "baz",
    srcs = ["//foo/bar/baz.go"],
)
```

See [What build rule contains file `src/main/java/com/example/cache/LRUCache.java` as a source?](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html#What_build_rule_contains_file_ja) and the rest of that page for more examples of `bazel query`.